# Exists operator in delete statement batch process?

Tags: oracle, exists

I want to know the order of the process, what first execute ..
 First I create table =>

```
SQL> create table ramin.tab001 ( id number, name varchar2(20));
Table created.
    SQL> select *from ramin.tab001;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 kamran
         2 emin
         3 ramin
         4 john
```

After this I am using correlated subquery with autotrace on option =>

```
SQL>delete from ramin.tab001 a where exists( select * from ramin.tab001 where id = a.id );
```

Execution plan =>

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 906765530

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT    |        |     6 |    36 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE             | TAB001 |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI    |        |     6 |    36 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB001 |     6 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB001 |     6 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID"="A"."ID")


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          7  db block gets
          6  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
       1204  redo size
        848  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
       1005  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          3  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          1  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          4  rows processed
```

I know that in correlated subquery order of process is =>
1. execute inner query
2. execute outer query and compares with the result of inner query
 
So I need experts opinion about order of process in statement or how I can check from autotrace ?

Comment: Answer: The order is exactly as determined by the execution plan.

Comment: The where exists inner query for the delete is completely unnecessary.  Basically it reads: "delete from this table where the key exists in the table" which will always evaluate to true.

Comment: You mean that outer query wants only one key from inner for delete all rows? But this is correlated, in this statement deleted only rows which in `2 - access("ID"="A"."ID")` , not all rows from table.

Comment: @nop77svk I cannot understand order in execution plan, is order begin from 4 to 0 ?

Comment: @KamranAbbasov, "how to read an execution plan" seems to be a different question than the one you asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to read an execution plan?**

The answer is simple. Read it as you would read a multilevel-nested call of functions in an imperative language.

**For example**, your execution plan

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT    |        |     6 |    36 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  DELETE             | TAB001 |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN SEMI    |        |     6 |    36 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB001 |     6 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB001 |     6 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID"="A"."ID")
```

can be read (in the form of an imperative pseudocode) simply as

```
delete(
    from: "TAB001",
    data_set_to_be_deleted: semi_join(
        join_algorithm: "hash join",
        leading_data_set: table_access(
            read_access_method: "full",
            table_name: "TAB001"
        ),
        trailing_data_set: table_access(
            read_access_method: "full",
            table_name: "TAB001",
            aliased_as: "A"
        ),
        join_condition: "ID = A.ID"
    )
)
```